# multiple animations triggered onScroll event with jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, animation, triggers, onscroll

I have a function that fades a particular DIV when scrolled into view. I have some child elements inside of these DIVs that I want to animate at the end of each fade animation. How can I add additional functions inside of the below function?

```
$(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
tiles.each(function(i) {
    a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
    b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(500,1) ???AND SLIDE CHILD ELEMENT ALSO!!???;
    ///how to I target each child element to do something in the above line???
    });
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BP6rq/451/) which will help you visualize my concept. The animations already work, the problem is that the sliding child elements start initially, what I want to do is start each slide function when each onScroll fade starts, consecutively. Thanks a lot in advance for this. This will help me out a ton with my trails and tribulations with jQuery!!

Comment: @NullPointer check the linked fiddle demo

Comment: Yes, looking at the demo you will instantly know what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do something after the fading is finished, create a callback function that is triggered, when the animation comes to an end:

```
var that = $(this);
if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(500,1, function() {
    alert ("Do something afterwards");
    that.children().someAction();
});
```

I hope, this is what you want.

To get your example working you can use this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
    tiles.each(function(i) {
        a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
        b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        var that = $(this);
        if (a < b && true != $(this).data('faded')) {
            $(this).data('faded', true).fadeTo(500,1, function() {
                that.find('div').animate({left: '+=300', top: '+=12'}, 4500);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mSRsA/

Comment: I plugged your code in with no success. I am guessing that it is not going to do what I am trying to achieve because the 'slide' animations need to be tied into an array so each individual SLIDE animation starts with each individual TILE fade on the onScroll event.

Comment: psuedo code: when first TILE fades in then scrollMe1 slides, when 2nd TILE fades in then scrollMe2 slides, when 3rd TILE...etc....

Comment: @user1644123 Check the fiddle in the updated answer - I hope I got you right. :)

Comment: @user1644123 Did you test the fiddle? It slides only once. See how I check whether the animation was already running using the `.data()`-method. The fiddle I've added should do what you want. :)

Comment: I don't see where you provided a fiddle demo..? However, look at mine: http://jsfiddle.net/BP6rq/466/ .... I slightly modified your code and it is actually working now!! Everything is perfect... EXCEPT the infinite slide loop... I tried adding .stop() to the end of the line but that broke the code so I took it out. Any thoughts? Thanks!!!

Comment: Oh okay, your right, if you quickly scroll once to the div then yes it only slides once but... if you do a scroll down slowing holding mouse click on the scroll bar it makes the slide repeat into a loop.... Weird bug... I am using FF16/windows7. Any idea why this happens?? Thanks again.

Comment: Tried it in Safari and in FireFox 16 (both MAC) and it works like a charm.

Comment: Okay... the bug is only apparent on my fiddle, not yours. Yours is complete, great work! Thanks again!